# How to use richtext in multifield (in CQ5 dialog)? (prevent "this.el.dom is undefined" error)

Tags: aem

I have created a custom component, and try to use RTE (`xtype="richtext"`) inside the multifiled in my dialog.

Now, when I try to delete item, or after dialog was closed & reopened add another one the dialog will neither close, nor save the data with OK button.

**dialog.xml:**

```
<myField
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./myField"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="richtext">
    </fieldConfig>
</myField>
```

Sham HC posted 2 solutions at [AEM FAQ's](http://aemfaq.blogspot.in/2013/04/richtext-in-multifield-widget.html):

> 1. Use `textfield` instead of a `richtext` Or try not to use a `richtext` in a `multifield`.
> 2. If `richtext` in a `multifield` is required then follow below and verify in your development envirnoment.
>
>    Overlay /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/RichText.js
>        At the overlayed file for the method syncValue (Line 910) replace [1] with [2].
>
>    ```
>    [1] this.el.dom.value = html;
>    [2] if(this.el.dom){this.el.dom.value = html;}
>    ```

The problem is that I would like to use make it without changing Adobe's code.

Answer (score 8):

I have found a workaround, that does not require changing CQ widget's code.
You need to set `richtext`'s `destroy` event handler, to create dummy `this.el.dom`:

```
<myField
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./myField"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="richtext">
        <listeners
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            destroy="function() {this.el.dom={};}"/>
    </fieldConfig>
</myField>
```

Comment: I have followed the advice given and it works like a charm. You can have nothing in the richtext or you can even delete it all in all and the ok button of the dialog will work with out any problem. Here is my code....

Answer (score 1):

```
<fieldConfig
       jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
       height="{Long}100"
       xtype="richtext">
       <listeners
           jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
           destroy="function() {this.el.dom={};}"/>
</fieldConfig>
```