# CQ5 multifield richtext not working

Tags: extjs, aem

I am having a richtext xtype as multifield to enter as many richtext items as author wanted for one of the component.

But, I am having below error in the browser developer tool console.

The error is coming when text entered is removed from a rich text field and click dialog "OK" button.

Could someone please help me?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I encountered the following post and it seems to be working.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474460/how-to-use-richtext-in-multifield-in-cq5-dialog-prevent-this-el-dom-is-unde](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474460/how-to-use-richtext-in-multifield-in-cq5-dialog-prevent-this-el-dom-is-unde)

Answer (score 0):

multifield widget won't work with any panel based widgets (including richtext), you should either :

- use the parsys / paragraph pattern in which you enter simple component with rich text, offering you the reorder / add / remove capabilities
- create your own widget to do what you want (but ext js dev for aem is kind of deprecated)